# Should I use an "else" to solve this?

Tags: c#

So, I'm still extremely new to the programming world and started learning with a YouTube video about C#.
Mid-way into the video he creates a calculator that let you choose which operator you wanna use (+, -, etc)
And because I wanted to not just copy his code I made changes so I can learn new things by myself, and what happened is basically this, at his code, if someone types an incorrect symbol (or anything else apart from + - * / ) it will give the user an error, but that only happens at the end (after the person types the 2nd number)

What I wanted to do is that if the person doesn't correctly type one of the 4 above symbols, they would receive an error straight away instead of at the end, and it kinda works, but the error appears even if the person correctly types the symbol! What I did wrong?

Here's the code (some parts are in Portuguese, but they're not relevant to the code itself):

```
using System;

namespace Calculadora

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo a calculadora");
            Console.WriteLine("Agora vamos fazer alguns cálculos");
            Console.Write("Para começar, escolha um número: ");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Agora, qual operação matemática você quer fazer? (Escolha entre +, -, * ou /): ");

            string op = Console.ReadLine();
            if (op != "+")
            if (op != "-")
            if (op != "*")
            if (op != "/")

            Console.WriteLine("Obs: esse erro foi escrito sem ajuda de um tutorial escrito");
            Console.WriteLine("Você digitou um comando de operação inválido, tente novamente");
            Console.WriteLine("Lembre se que os comandos valídos são: + | - | * | / ");
            Console.ReadLine();
           
            Console.Write("Escolha o outro número: ");
            double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O resultado é: ");
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O resultado é: ");
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O resultado é: ");
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O resultado é: ");
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it so that if the user correctly types the symbol they just continue with the operation?

Edit1: I added the {} after the first 'if' and put the error message between the brackets, did the same with the other if's but added an else before it, still the same problem!

Comment: Well, you should start by getting rid of the extra single-line `if`s earlier in the code that are syntax errors and don't serve any purpose.

Comment: if (op != "+")
if (op != "-")
if (op != "*")
if (op != "/"), think about this...

Comment: You should use curly brackets `{}` after `if`.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint on your 2nd if statement `if (op != "-")`. If it hits, you should continue through the code execution. I highly doubt it hits though as @Johnny points out. Also, a switch statement would help simplify all the if/else statements you are going through. Debugging your code is very helpful when trying to see what it's doing and why you're not getting the results you expected. I'm still learning and that has helped me a lot!

Comment: if you have ' a lot of ' nested if statements, it might be better to use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: @Luuk Didn't learn that yet, so I'm trying to make one with what I currently know!

Comment: So, what should I do to ignore the error part if the user types the correct symbol?

Comment: You should make sure the correct symbol, any of (+ - * /), is entered before continuing. Because if you do not know the symbol, a second  number is useless...

Comment: Did you alread surround the 4 lines (starting from `Console.WriteLine("Obs: esse ....`) with curly brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (op != "+")
if (op != "-")
if (op != "*")
if (op != "/")
```

The problem is with the above line of code.Lets suppose I enter '+',so the first if statements evaluate to false and the rest to true.But the control flow executes the below lines of code no matter what:

```
Console.WriteLine("Obs: esse erro foi escrito sem ajuda de um tutorial escrito");
Console.WriteLine("Você digitou um comando de operação inválido, tente novamente");
Console.WriteLine("Lembre se que os comandos valídos são: + | - | * | / ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I think it would be interesting for you if I give this much of a hint.

EDIT: Please tell the reason when downvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the four tests in a single expression and write

```
if (op != "+" && op != "-" && op != "*" && op != "/") {
    Console.WriteLine("Obs: esse erro foi escrito sem ajuda de um tutorial escrito");
    Console.WriteLine("Você digitou um comando de operação inválido, tente novamente");
    Console.WriteLine("Lembre se que os comandos valídos são: + | - | * | / ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

by making sure not to forget the braces around the code to be executed when the condition is true.

But since the user must re-enter the operation sign if he enters something wrong, better use a loop

```
while (true) {
    Console.Write("Agora, qual operação matemática você quer fazer? (Escolha entre +, -, * ou /): ");
    string op = Console.ReadLine();

    if ("+-*/".Contains(op) && op.Length == 1) break; // exit the loop.

    Console.WriteLine("Obs: esse erro foi escrito sem ajuda de um tutorial escrito");
    Console.WriteLine("Você digitou um comando de operação inválido, tente novamente");
    Console.WriteLine("Lembre se que os comandos valídos são: + | - | * | / ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```